# Give access to certain folder and fonts with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a code to redirect all users to soon.php except those with certain page 
should see the content in .htaccess ..

The code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soon\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/soon.php [R=307,L]
```

But when i look at soon.php the images and fonts are missing 
which are located in another subfolder named

```
/soon/images
/soon/fonts
```

How can i give soon.php which is in root directory access to those directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try excluding requests with a certain referer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soon\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !soon\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/soon.php [R=307,L]
```

Or, just exclude the `/soon/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soon\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soon/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/soon.php [R=307,L]
```